# Problem installing libpng-dev along with libpng12-dev on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: pi, openalpr

I am trying to install OPENALPR on my Pi Zero and I am using the instructions on
https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/baxwz5/how_to_install_openalpr_on_raspberry_pi/

After I run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool libleptonica-dev libicu-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo2-dev cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev python-dev python-numpy libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev virtualenvwrapper liblog4cplus-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libtiff5-dev libpng12-dev gcc make ca-certificates autoconf-archive
```

I get the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng-dev : Conflicts: libpng12-dev but 1.2.54-6 is to be installed
 libpng12-dev : Conflicts: libpng-dev but 1.6.36-6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing packages in smaler groups (instead of all at once) works but libpng-dev is removed in the process

How to solve the incompatibility above?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace libpng12-dev with libpng-dev

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).